# histogram equalization code put there is an error in matplotlib

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv, matplotlib

**the code is:**

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('home.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('baby',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#plt.hist(img.ravel(),256,[0,256]); plt.show()
```

**the problem appearce is**
[image]

Comment: Please copy the error here as text, not as image

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling matplotlib and then reinstalling it.

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Anaconda/miniconda is also a good option to try. (anaconda comes with matplotlib installed)